# UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage save image with black color background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to save my image. However, if I pick an image and adjust the image zoom, it will save with incomplete image (with black color background as below). How can I save fit image in this case?
Please help. Thank you.
[image]

My current code here:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    image = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(200,200)]; // or some other size

    if (image == nil) {
        image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    }

    if (image.imageOrientation != UIImageOrientationUp) {
        image = [self fixOrientation:image];
    }
    if (_imageName==nil || _imageName.length == 0) {

        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
        NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        _imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo_%@.png",dateStr];
    }

    [[self getCurrentVC] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectPhotoManagerDidFinishImage:)]) {
        [_delegate selectPhotoManagerDidFinishImage:image];
    }

    if (_successHandle) {
        _successHandle(self,image);
    }
}

- (UIImage *) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: are you getting value in first statement where you have assign the UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage image?

Comment: @dreamBegin, I getting this in 1st statement :- `<UIImage: 0x1c04b7be0> size {1122, 1062} orientation 0 scale 1.000000`

Comment: put a break point after `image = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(200,200)];` statement and see what your getting

Comment: Hi @dreamBegin, I getting this `<UIImage: 0x6000004be2a0> size {200, 200} orientation 0 scale 3.000000
` Any idea to solve this?

Comment: where you're showing this image? imageview if yes what is the content mode of the imageview?

Comment: @dreamBegin, showing in a collectionview. The image saved with black space background as per screenshot. Not related to content mode i think.

Comment: strange issue.. i can't tell exactly what is wrong here due to lack of explanation but why are you dismissing you view controller earlier and then firing your delegate? you should put that code in completion handler of  `dismissViewControllerAnimated ` method.

Comment: @dreamBegin, this issue happen when I zoom out and drag image multiple times to left side before save. I still stuck over here. Anyway, thanks for your help!